# Single word for being evil but enjoying it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know of words such as 'malign' but I am specifically looking for a word that not only expresses evilness/violence but also an enjoyment/choice to do such 'activity', as oppose to someone who does it because they are ordered to or because they 'have to' for survival for example.

Example: The way John handled himself with Jack, he was clearly ______ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *[malevolent](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/malevolent)*, *[malicious](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/malicious)*, *[sadistic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sadistic)*, or *[vixenish](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/vixenish)*.

Malicious or sadistic would probably fit your scenario best.

While all four words imply evil/violent, malicious and sadistic both mean taking pleasure in such acts.

Although, the other two words are still good options depending on the context of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Is "malicious" the word you want?

From Cambridge dictionary "intended to harm or upset other people".

Note here that harm is stated to be the intent and not stated to be a by-product. Note also that there are expressions such as "malicious smile" where a smile is normally presumed to indicate enjoyment. These suggest to me that the word implies a choice to do the actions and possibly implies enjoyment of them.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [***mischievous***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mischievous) (Collins) as well:

> causing or showing a fondness for causing trouble in a playful way.

[***Impish***](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02Y_eA7i79uZKTA6vKMUm4BCczWzA%3A1608294990825&ei=TqLcX4fvMcKD8gKZ-L-4CA&q=impish&oq=impish&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMg8IABCxAxDJAxBDEEYQ-QEyCggAELEDEBQQhwIyCAgAELEDEIMBMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoJCCMQJxBGEPkBOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoLCC4QsQMQxwEQowI6DgguELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOgcIABDJAxBDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgUILhCxAzoICC4QsQMQgwE6BwguELEDEEM6BQgAELEDOgoIABCxAxDJAxBDOgcIABCxAxBDOgcIABAUEIcCOgIILjoICAAQsQMQyQM6BAgAEAo6CggAELEDEIMBEApQnDxYvlVguHdoAnAAeACAAaYCiAGaDZIBBTAuMy41mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab) also describes well the connotation you are looking for.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impish) has nice examples with this word.

Comment: _impish/ mischievous_ and _violence_? No!  These are used for innocuous pranks.

Answer (score 1):

While often used with a sexual connotation, [sadism](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/sadism) doesn't have to be sexual.

> Sadism is a type of behavior in which a person obtains pleasure from hurting other people and making them suffer physically or mentally.